# Unexpected Result with C++ Ansynchronous IO

Tags: c++, io, c++17

From the Linux command line I need to run "foo | bar". I am coding bar, which reads input from standard in (piped from foo). Note that foo runs indefinitely.

The following code simulates the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m{};

class Reader {

private:

    std::istream& in;
    std::thread* myThread = nullptr;
    bool threadContinue = false;

public:

    Reader(std::istream& in) :
            in { in }
    {
        using namespace std;
        threadContinue = true;
        myThread = new thread { [&]() {
            while(this->threadContinue) {
                m.lock();
                cout << "." << in.peek() << " ";
                while(in.peek()>=0) {
                    string line {};
                    getline(in, line);
                    cout << line << " "; // Do something important...
                }
                m.unlock();
                if(!this->threadContinue) {
                    break;
                }
                this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            }
            cout << "STOPPED" << endl;
        } };
    }

    void stop() {
        assert(threadContinue);
        threadContinue = false;
        myThread->join();
        delete myThread;
        myThread = nullptr;
    }

};

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    stringstream io { };
    Reader r { io };

    m.lock();
    io << "A" << endl;
    io << "B" << endl;
    io << "C" << endl;
    io.flush();
    m.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));

    m.lock();
    io << "D" << endl;
    io << "E" << endl;
    io << "F" << endl;
    io.flush();
    m.unlock();

    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));

    r.stop();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `.65 A B C .-1 .-1 .-1 .-1 .-1 STOPPED`

What am I doing wrong? I would like D E F processed as well.

I this possible in C++17 without Boost?

[... I have tried using peek(), getline() without peek, and considered the attributes of the stream, but to no avail ...]

[... I have added a mutex and controlled access to the stream, but this is not helping, the output is as before ...]

Comment: You have to protect the access to C++-streams by a mutex. They are *not* thread-safe. As for now, your code has UB.

Comment: I have updated the code with mutex control, but the output is as before.

Comment: The stringstream has already entered eof state when you `peek` without data available, so all subsequent operations simply error out. It might work if you `clear()` after you've locked it. This is a pure guess, so I'm not posting it as an answer.

Comment: If you want to stop the reader thread after all input is processed, stop the reader thread after all input is processed. Not after a set amount of time. There is no guarantee whatsoever about timing. You also need to protect threadContinue with a mutex or make it atomic.

Comment: I tried commenting out sleep of 300 ms between writing A,B,C and D,E,F characters and since stream is good to read hence getting expected output as you want.

Comment: Also You should ideally check whether a stream is good to read using istream::good().

Comment: It is also unclear how this code is related to your original problem. If foo runs indefinitely, bar will never see eof.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl : Indeed. In the reader, clearing in just before unlocking makes the code work as posted. Not sure what that will mean when in=cin and foo is generating the data. But, a solution to the code as posted. You may wish to post as answer.

Comment: @n.m This is my attempt at a unit test. The Reader is normally instantiated with cin, and I am unit testing the reader. Are you saying that cin just behaves differently. Foo is piping lines, but not continually. Every so often it pipes a line.

Comment: It doesn't matter how often. There will be no eof until foo closes the standard output. A stringstream is not a pipe, it behaves totally differently.

Comment: @n.m Thanks. I worded my problem badly, but you solved my real problem.